# How can I run a function on initialization of a struct?

Tags: rust

I have a struct:

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    pub a: i32,
    pub b: i32,
}
```

When instantiating `MyStruct`, I want to divide `a` by 2:

```rust
let a = MyStruct { a: 26, b: 42 };
println!("{:?}", a);
// MyStruct { a: 13, b: 42 }
```

Is it possible for it to happen automatically or do I have to create a `instantiate` function and call it every time I create a `MyStruct`?

Comment: If the fields weren't public, outside of the module in which `MyStruct` is declared (and its descendents) you'd be forced to instantiate it using a constructor function—where you can implement arbitrary initialisation logic of this sort.

Comment: there is no concept of constructor in rust, yes you would need to create a function to automatic the feature

Comment: @Stargateur: I (and [The Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html?highlight=Constructor#associated-functions)) refer to associated functions that return a new instance of `Self` as “constructors”.

Comment: @eggyal better avoid the confusion with other language, I also call them constructor but to someone new to the language I would avoid the term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would want to create a module as @eggyal suggested in a comment.  Here's a code sample that illustrates how that might be written:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStructLiteral {
    pub a: i32,
    pub b: i32,
}

mod foo {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct MyStruct {
        a: i32,
        b: i32,
    }
    
    impl MyStruct {
        pub fn new(a: i32, b: i32) -> MyStruct {
            MyStruct { a: a / 2, b: b / 2 }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = MyStructLiteral { a: 26, b: 42 };
    println!("{:?}", a);

    let alt = foo::MyStruct::new(26, 42);
    println!("{:?}", alt);
}
```

Here it is in the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=87eea91a8753ae3e6b9d2be937d47145)

The output is:

```
MyStructLiteral { a: 26, b: 42 }
MyStruct { a: 13, b: 21 }
```

Steve Klabnik has a good blog post covering [Structure literals vs. constructors in Rust](https://steveklabnik.com/writing/structure-literals-vs-constructors-in-rust)

Note that if you want to call `MyStruct::new` and not have to use the module name, you can `use` the module so you don't have to prefix the module name:

```
use self::foo::MyStruct;
```

Comment: Thank you ! The trick is to not make the arguments public then. If I then want to access them from outside the module, I would need to add accessor function in the `impl MyStruct` block then ?

Comment: yep!  here's an example of accessor function for `a`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e5df98227b34c5132302dc77d787d0dd

Comment: What about on initialization of an enum?

Answer (score 3):

To mirror what was said in the comments, yes, you have to create an explicit function to handle construction logic.

```rust
impl MyStruct {
    fn new(a: i32, b: i32) -> MyStruct {
        // Special code goes here ...
        MyStruct { a, b }
    }
}
```

Normally, if you're doing special work on construction, you'll probably be encapsulating some concept, hence you'll probably want to have private fields. If you genuinely do want all of your fields to be public but don't want to allow explicit construction, you can add a zero-sized private field like `()`.

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    pub a: i32,
    pub b: i32,
    _private: (),
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn new(a: i32, b: i32) -> MyStruct {
        // Special code goes here ...
        MyStruct { a, b, _private: () }
    }
}
```

Now it's impossible to directly construct `MyStruct` outside of the module because it has a private field that we only know how to construct.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate on this example? I tried it here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b9b3f10d38bb86e7fc5a91e5fc52a9d8 but it did not work. (i.e. the function `new` was never used).

Comment: I see, one need to call `let a = MyStruct::new(26, 42);` (notice the new) instead of `let a = MyStruct {a: 26, b: 42};`. Is there a way that a new `struct` always calls the `::new` function? (like `__init__` in python)? Also to change `a` and `b` I had to made them mutable: `fn new(mut a: i32, mut b: i32) -> MyStruct {` (just for the original question, to divide `a` by to, `a` has to mutable I guess) (sorry I am new to rust so maybe I am wrong here.) https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=40e1d98cfa3d5578d0463466ebfcc193

Comment: No, the literal struct syntax `MyStruct { ... }` does *not* call any functions or operators. Rust has no constructor syntax that you can override. If you want to have a "constructor" (in the sense of a language like Python), you write a factory function and call it `new`. The name `new` isn't special; it's just a convention, but it's still an ordinary associated function. And yes, to reassign to a variable, that variable has to be marked `mut`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, even while the answer was old.